# How to measure the extent of vertical integration by using the ratio of Income to Sales

Tags: econometrics

I am was reading a research paper called "Concept and statistical measurement of vertical integration" by author M.A.Adelman . This research paper proposes that the extent to which some company is vertically integrated can be known by observing the ratio of Income to Sales. Firstly, I don't really understand what do income and sales mean in this context and how could they be used to measure the extent of vertical integration. Secondly, I would really appreciate if someone could present me a way in which I could use this ratio to calculate the extent of vertical integration of some firm using data from some company's quarterly earnings report. Any help would be much appreciated.